# Reusing a PDO connection after execute?

Tags: php, oop, object, pdo, database-connection

I would like to know if it's correct to re-use a PDO db connection multiple times ?

For example, I set it up in my controller then pass it as a parameter in a constructor of a class, is it correct to call the same connection (by using a function like get_Database) thoughout all my functions in the class and even pass it as a parameter in another class construct to continue working with the same connection ?

Or should I reopen a connection at some point ?

I was able to get it working by simply passing it around, however I am not quite sure if this would be performing well when going live.

Comment: Its not only OK its recommended. Making a connection is a comparatively slow process. Always reuse the connection throughout a single script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you should reuse the connection.

> Or should I reopen a connection at some point ?

The only reason to open a new connection is if connecting to another database. Otherwise, throughout a single script only one connection should be used.

To achieve this it is important to try and avoid using a static singleton throughout your application, rather learn about [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to design your code to share the same PDO instance to every function or class that needs it.

> however I am not quite sure if this would be performing well when going live.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639848/reusing-a-pdo-connection-after-execute/35647411#comment58961556_35639848), if you reopen a connection often, it will be a lot *slower*.

---

There are many dependency injector's out there, and it is almost certainly a matter of opinion, but I like [Auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn). Learning about it should help you design code where it is easier to share a single PDO instance, amongst others.

Comment: Why is it important to avoid a singleton for PDO?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is OK and it is better than connecting to the database many times.
The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) even suggests to use the opened connection between calls to your php script / application:

> Many web applications will benefit from making persistent connections to database servers. Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web application.